# PHP: array_search returning null

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have a regular array that contains numbers from 1 to 14 that is generated by retrieving INTs from a SQL result column.

Using another query I'm returning another INT.

I'm searching for this INT in my array.

```
$key = array_search("$roomNb", $freeRooms);
```

However when I try to echo this key nothing appears. It is empty.

If I echo $freeRooms using a loop I get:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
14
```

If I echo $roomNb I get

```
5
```

So I can't understand why I'm not getting anything in return. I should be expecting a key of 4 no? What could be causing this?

Comment: Don't just use echo - use `var_dump($roomNb, $freeRooms)`. I'm willing to bet there's an extra space or other character in your needle or haystack. In general, `var_dump` can help you fix all your code problems :-)

Comment: @Itay quotes make no difference — array_search is non-strict by default. (OK, technically not true, if the array contained `string("5 ")` and $roomNb was `int(5)`, then this *would* make a difference…)

Comment: I just replicated the scenario in my terminal and it worked fine, maybe try casting (int) when you're storing the values in the array?

Comment: @cbuckley - I think even in that case it's OK. `$a = ['4', '5 ', '6'];
echo array_search(5, $a);` that echoes 1, since PHP's string->int conversion looks for the first non-whitespace character and then checks if that is the start of a sequence of digits before the next non-digit character matching the search input. It would even work if the value in the array were '5g' or ' 5 6' (space between the 5 and 6).

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox yes, my point was that the quotes *would* make a difference in that scenario, as `array_search('5', ['5 '])` would return false! There was a deleted comment that said removing the quotes around `$roomNb` would fix it.

Comment: @cbuckley - quotes, right. I misread your comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely `$key` is `false` which when sent to echo will appear as nothing.  Instead you should use `var_dump` to determine the value of `$key`

`False` is returned from `array_search` when the needle is not found

`Null` is only returned when the parameters you pass to `array_search` are invalid

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Test this code here using http://writecodeonline.com/php/:

```
echo false;
echo null;
var_dump(false);
var_dump(null);

$code = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14);
$roomNb = 5;

var_dump(array_search("$roomNb", $code));
```

Should work just fine.  `echo` will output nothing. `var_dump` will output stuff. And the key is found at 4.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your array will always contain contiguous numbers, and you can verify that your second SQL call returns one of those numbers, I would say something like

```
$value = $freeRooms[$roomNb]
```

I'm personally unfamiliar with how array_search executes, however if you wanted to write your own, I assume it would look something like this

```
function IndexOf($searchValue,$array)
{
    $i = 0;
    for( $i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++ ) 
        if( $array[$i] == $searchValue )
            return $i;
}
```

Comment: The array doesn't contain contiguous numbers: it starts with 1, not 0, and it skips 13.